# |New to Php| How can I install this to php

Tags: php, composer-php

Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

```
      Problem 1
        - intervention/image is locked to version 2.5.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
        - intervention/image 2.5.0 requires ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
      Problem 2
        - league/flysystem is locked to version 1.0.53 and an update of this package was not requested.
        - league/flysystem 1.0.53 requires ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
      Problem 3
        - league/flysystem 1.0.53 requires ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
        - tcg/voyager v1.2.6 requires league/flysystem ~1.0.41 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.0.53].
        - tcg/voyager is locked to version v1.2.6 and an update of this package was not requested
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple edit your php.ini file and enable the fileinfo extension. All extensions that are disabled are shown starting from a ; semicolon and every enabled one does not have the semicolon ; before it.

Here is the image[image]